# statement even working and executing fine without the semicolon

Tags: c, output

so i just wrote below mentioned program:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b = 120;
    a = -b--;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is a = -120, b = 119 , which is fine for me , but when i run the above program with slight modification it gives some strange results.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b = 120;
    a = b---      *// strange here , because program run without semicolon here.*
    printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

i wonder why this program is able to run and i don't see any error even though i haven't closed the statement.

Edit: If there is no semicolon then for compiler it means the same statement until unless it sees a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code (after removing the syntax error caused by the comment) reads

```
a = b-- - printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
```

Since `printf` returns a value, that is valid code. When I initialise

```
int a = 0;
```

the program output is

```
a = 0, b = 120
```

In C end-of-line does not mean end-of-statement.

Comment: @CherubimAnand as you know - that's why I initialised `a`. But is the usage of `b` undefined? The question asked why the program compiles.

Comment: ya i do understand why it compiles, but i think the behavior is defined, please have a look at this : https://ideone.com/xXID9d , **it's just the value of** `a` **that's indeterminate I think.**

Comment: `is the usage of b undefined?` I think it's technically `undetermined` since `C` doesn't guarantee an order of evaluation in this case. So the output could be `= 120` or `= 119` but nothing else.

Comment: @CherubimAnand sorry I meant the *printed* value of `b`. Obviously the original value of `a` was undefined in OP's code, and in my snippet, the final value of `a` could also be undefined, especially if `int b=100` when the return value from `printf` could be undefined depending on whether it prints `b` as `99` or `100`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works because `printf()` returns an int (the number of characters printed), so your operation is

```
a = (b--) - (printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b));
```

Comment: @2501 wrong. The code **works** (if you compile it without any flag), but the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The code compiles, but it doesn't 'work' if you don't want undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 well, okay, it depends what you mean by 'work' - the main ends without any error and the program doesn't crash at runtime. The behavior is wrong (like there is a bug), but IMO you can't say a program doesn't work because there is a bug. But this is more a philosophical difference. Since the question is `i wonder why this program is able to run and i don't see any error even though i haven't closed the statement.` I think my answer is correct, I explain why there isn't any error and why the program runs.

Comment: Undefined behavior - b is both used and modified in the same statement.

Comment: *you can't say a program doesn't work because there is a bug.* I disagree with that statement.

Comment: @2501 yes, I understood that and I agree we disagree :) Anyway, the question is 'why does it run and why I don't see any error', and well, the explanation is my answer

Comment: The code exhibits UB (undefined behavior), twice. `a` is used without having been initialized, and `b` is modified and used without an intermediate sequence point. UB doesn't guarantee a crash, but that doen't mean the code *works*.

Comment: @vishwaratna The code compiles because it is syntactically correct in `C`, as pointed out in the answer above. On the other hand, the code exhibits UB so *anything* can happen when you run it. What you see is one possible outcome of UB.

Answer (score 1):

Unary minus and unary decrement DO NOT have the same precedence.  Unary decrement is higher.  Were unary minus higher, the decrement could not be applied, as its argument would be an expression but not an lvalue, and only an lvalue can be decremented.

I have no idea what "haven't closed the statement" means.  Do you mean the function definition that ends with '}'?

***// strange here , because program run without semicolon here.*** ?  First of all, it wouldn't COMPILE without the semicolon, let alone run.  Also, you don't use ***//** to begin a comma, so that wouldn't compile either.  It runs because a previous version without these errors compiled and linked successfully and generated an a.out; you are, without question, re-executing this old a.out.